# How to disable other select boxes based on one select box that has changed?

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

1. I have some select boxes (sometimes they are 2, sometimes 3 or 10, maybe 20 and more)
2. All of them have selected options.

I want to change one of them to another option and automatically have other select boxes disabled!

```
<select name="SELECT[0]">
  <option selected value="01">text1</option>
  <option value="02">text2</option>
  <option value="03">text3</option>
  <option value="04">text4</option>
  <option value="nn">textn</option>
</select> 
<select name="SELECT[1]">
  <option selected value="01">text1</option>
  <option value="02">text2</option>
  <option value="03">text3</option>
  <option value="04">text4</option>
  <option value="nn">textn</option>
</select> 
<select name="SELECT[2]">
  <option selected value="01">text1</option>
  <option value="02">text2</option>
  <option value="03">text3</option>
  <option value="04">text4</option>
  <option value="nn">textn</option>
</select> 
<select name="SELECT[3]">
  <option selected value="01">text1</option>
  <option value="02">text2</option>
  <option value="03">text3</option>
  <option value="04">text4</option>
  <option value="nn">textn</option>
</select> 
<select name="SELECT[n]">
  <option selected value="01">text1</option>
  <option value="02">text2</option>
  <option value="03">text3</option>
  <option value="04">text4</option>
  <option value="nn">textn</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Need to provide a lot more detail in order for others to understand your issue. Please take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Comment: In my question, here we have 5 select boxes. How to disable SELECT[0], SELECT[1], SELECT[2] and SELECT[n] when user changes the selected option on SELECT[3] to any other option?

Comment: Yes ... we can count that also. Doesn't explain much

Comment: jQuery is already in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

The key is [the "selection" type attribute of jQuery's `.not` method](https://api.jquery.com/not/#not-selection).

```
$("select").change(function () {
  $("select").not($(this)).attr("disabled", "true");
});
```